# Метод не начинает считывать последующие строчки

Tags: java, строки

Есть код, который должен разбивать строчки из базы (`тхт` файла) и выводить их, но код только первую строчку читает и забивает на него.
Как решить данную проблему?

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class getEncrypt {
public String getEncryptMethod(String in){
File lib = new File("lib.txt");
String str;
String[] phasa1;
String[] phasa2;
String cryptedNames = "Ошибка";

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lib));
    for(;(str = br.readLine())!= null;){
        cryptedNames = "Дошел до разбивки массива";
        phasa1 = str.split("=");

        phasa2 = phasa1[0].split(",");
        cryptedNames = "Дошел до этапа 2";
        try {
            cryptedNames = "Дошел до этапа 3";
            for (String i:phasa2) {
                System.out.println(i);
                if(i.equalsIgnoreCase(in)) {
                    cryptedNames = phasa1[1];
                }else {
                    cryptedNames = "Fuck :(";
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return cryptedNames;
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println(e);
}
return cryptedNames;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getEncryptMethod(String in) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String fileName = "lib.txt";
    String str;
    String[] phasa1;
    String[] phasa2;
    String cryptedNames = "Ошибка";

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            str = sc.nextLine();
            cryptedNames = "Дошел до разбивки массива";
            phasa1 = str.split("=");
            phasa2 = phasa1[0].split(",");
            cryptedNames = "Дошел до этапа 2";
            cryptedNames = "Дошел до этапа 3";
            for (String i : phasa2) {
                System.out.println(i);
                if (i.equalsIgnoreCase(in)) cryptedNames = phasa1[1];
                else cryptedNames = "Fuck :(";
            }
            return cryptedNames;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return cryptedNames;
}
```

Comment: Читать файл в данном случае проще сканером. Каждая итерация цикла будет присваивать переменной str следующую строку. Причина существования переменной cryptedNames для меня осталось загадкой, поэтому бейтесь с ней сами... Как и вообще этого кода... Если вы ищите какую-то подстроку в строке текста, то у стринга есть метод contains, который справится с этой задачей без проблем. Итого читаете файл построчно, вызываете указанный метод, получаете результат. Все ок. Если надо без учета регистра, то... Подумайте сами